# What is the background music being played in Akame Ga Kill Season1 Episode 9 around 7:43 when we are introduced to all the jaegers?

Tags: music, akame-ga-kill

For the life of me I havent been able to find the background music that is played when Wave first meets bols and bols is staring at him and we are slowly introduced to all jaegers. I have gone through all soundtracks for Akame Ga Kill on YouTube and found no results.

Please please help. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

disk 2, nr 6 Jaegers (イェーガーズ, Jaegers)

The title is pretty obvious.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMKgVNwzozY

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND IT ! Finally after all this time lol

It’s called ‘impression’. It’s track 2 from the Akami Ga Kill soundtrack. It’s on YouTube